# TypeError: __str__ returned non-string

Tags: python, eclipse, python-3.x, iterator

```
class Course(object):
    def __init__(self,cnum,name):
        self.name = name
        self.cnum = cnum
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Course:' , self.cnum  , self.name

class AssigendCourse(Course):
    def __init__(self,Course,dept,year,semester):
        self.name = Course.name
        self.cnum = Course.cnum
        if dept == 'SE' or dept == 'CE' or dept == 'CIE' or dept == 'ME':
            self.dept = dept
        else:
            self.dept = None
        if year >= 1 and year <= 4:
            self.year = year
        else:
            self.year = None
        if semester >= 1 and semester <= 3:
            self.semester = semester
        else:
            self.semester = None
    def __str__(self):
        return 'Course: ' , self.name , self.cnum
```

results in this type of error

```
TypeError: __str__ returned non-string (type tuple)
```

I can't figure what type of syntax I need to use for the `__str__` func in order to get the print for the object when using:

```
it = iter(db)
for i in it:
    print(i)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your `__str__` methods return **tuples**:

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'Course:' , self.cnum  , self.name
```

The comma makes it it tuple.

You'll need to join those values; I recommend string formatting:

```
def __str__(self):
    return 'Course: {} {}'.format(self.cnum, self.name)
```

Comment: Thanks much.. Simple and elegant solution! +1